# How can I Make Relation Between My Report And My Filter In Dashboard Designer?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ssas, performancepoint, dashboard-designer

I use `Share Point 2010` and i want create a `Dashboard` with `Dashboard Designer` in `Performance Point Service`.

And I Use `SQL Server 2008 R2` and `SSAS`

I use `Adventure WorkDW 2008` data base for test.

I create a report that called 'Sales Amount In Date' like this picture :

[image: Report Picture]

And then I create `Custom Filter` that called `My Date Filter` like this picture :

[image: Filter Picture]

After this I create a tow row `Dashboard Page` that called `My Filter Report` like this picture :

[image]

How I can make relation between my Filter and my Report?

Because after deploying my dashboard I have this page :

[image: Deployed Page]

But my filter has not relation with my report ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mouse over the filter to expand it. Drag the filter value you want to send to the report, probably Member Unique Name, and drop it on the report filter area. Select what dimension on the report you want to apply the filter to. In the example, I'm connecting a filter called Date to a scorecard called Sales Quota.

[image]

[image]

[image]